# Accessing .tar files within .tar files

Tags: python, tar

I have a tar archive that contains some other tar archives. The following example extracts the primary .tar file perfectly but I'm having a problem getting to the other .tar files within.

```
import tarfile
import os

fd = tarfile.open('test.tar')
for member in fd.getmembers():
    if not member.isfile():
        continue

    cfile = fd.extractfile(member)
    name = cfile.name
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(name)
    #print filename + "----" + file_extension

    if file_extension == ".tar":
        print cfile
    #print cfile.read()
    print cfile.name
    cfile.close()
fd.close()
```

This returns the following:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
<tarfile.ExFileObject object at 0x101989690>
tar1.tar
```

So I can get to the tar1.tar file object. However I can't work out how to get the members or content from tar1.tar.

Comment: ... the same way you're doing it for the main tar file?

Comment: Yes I tried that but `getmembers()` doesnt exits for the `tarfile.ExFileObject` object

Comment: You might try do it recursivelly and I don't know if you can do that w/out extracting it first. Are you using python2 or 3? If you give me access to that file you have I can give it a shot and post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your `cfile` as the `fileobj` parameter to a new call to `tarfile.open()`.

```
import tarfile
import os

def list_contents(name, fileobj=None, prefix=''):
    fd = tarfile.open(name, fileobj=fileobj)
    for member in fd.getmembers():
        if not member.isfile():
            continue
        cfile = fd.extractfile(member)
        name = cfile.name
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(name)
        print prefix + cfile.name
        if file_extension == '.tar':
            list_contents(name, cfile, prefix+'    ')
        cfile.close()
    fd.close

list_contents('x.tar')
```

Test:

```
$ touch a b c x y z
$ tar cf y.tar x y z
$ tar cf x.tar a b y.tar c
$ python t.py
a
b
y.tar
    x
    y
    z
c
```

Comment: Thanks Perfect ! - If I want to selectivly get the content for each file based on its file path/name is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to add code to do that. Give a try. If you get stuck, you can always ask another question on [so]!